# Is this using alias for a function type (not pointer) the same as this typedef

Tags: c++, c++11, typedef, using

Are these the same?

```
using on_receipt = void (const string);

typedef void on_receipt(const string);
```

These are not aliasing a function pointer, but rather an actual function type. They both compile fine. What seems odd is that the `typedef` version at least has the placeholder for the name of the function, but since the `using` moves this placeholder before the `=`, there is nothing separating the return and the parameters, which looks like it could be incorrect or misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes they are:

> **[dcl.typedef]**
>
> 2 A typedef-name can also be introduced by an
>   alias-declaration. The identifier following the `using` keyword becomes
>   a typedef-name and the optional attribute-specifier-seq following the
>   identifier appertains to that typedef-name. It has the same semantics
>   as if it were introduced by the `typedef` specifier. In particular, it
>   does not define a new type.

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3c00713d81cfb4e)

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    using on_receipt1 = void (const std::string);    
    typedef void on_receipt2(const std::string);
    static_assert(std::is_same<on_receipt1, on_receipt2>::value, "");
}
```

Comment: Probably best idea for hard-evidence =). Kudos. +1

Comment: A simpler test that doesn't require `<type_traits>` is `using on_receipt = void (const std::string); typedef void on_receipt(const std::string);`. You can redeclare typedefs - but only if both declarations name the same type.

Answer (score 0):

You think about it wrong. `on_receipt` is not a "place holder for a function name" it is a typename you introduce. Think about the usage.

You would use it like `on_receipt function_variable;`, so your interpretation is actually misleading, because the "name" by which you would refer your function is not `on_receipt` but `function_variable`.

I would say that the `typedef` syntax for functions is rather odd. In `using` style you have the type name on one side, and the thing defining it on the the other. In the `typedef` style you have it interleaved.

`typedef` kinda looks like a function declaration, but it really isn't; it's a type declaration. I find that messy.

Oh, of course, those statements are equivalent.